# SWFobject on top of JS tooltips

Tags: javascript, flash, dom, xhtml, swfobject

http://richarcade.com/play/gunrun

I'm using swfobject.js (richarcade.com/swfobject.js) to display Flash content, and wz_tooltip.js (richarcade.com/wz_tooltip.js) to display hovered tooltips. The problem is that the 'similar games' tooltips show up behind the flash game. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, the flash will be rendered 'above' the webpage. This means tooltips will appear below the flash movie all the time. To fix this, you can set the WMODE attribute of the flash movie to 'transparent' or 'opaque'. After that you should be able to set the z-index order as you can with any other HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you've got the flash content( embedded with swfobject ) in one div ( #flashcontent for example ) and the wz_tooltip.js content in another div. The tooltip div should be sorted above the flash content div. Using [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp) should do the trick. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can it be a span instead of a div? I tried z-index but it didn't work and I don't know how to use it properly. Can you explain how I can put it in a JS-generated tooltip?